# Application/pdf response from API call interpreted as text/xml

Tags: angular, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

I have backend Spring Boot 2 app deployed as Azure Web App. It connects with Angular frontend deployed as Azure Static Web App. My backend generates pdf file which is sent as byte[] with 'application/pdf' header. Frontend App gets reponse as Blob and displays it.
It worked on my local environment and worked also for some time on Azure. Unoftunately it stopped working on Azure (still works locally). It's a group project and many changes were made in the whole code (but not in the given functionality). I tried to fix this issue for four days and the only trail I found was addition of staticwebapp.config.json file.
I need to make this work back on Azure, thanks for all help!
Current error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0NSI.png)
Backend (Azure Web App)

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generateAndDownloadPdfFile(String templateName, Map<String, Object> data, List<String> fonts) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(data);

        String htmlContent = templateEngine.process(templateName, context);

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream target = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            for (String font : fonts) {
                renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(font, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            }

            fonts.stream().forEach(font -> {
                try {
                    renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(font, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(target, false);
            renderer.finishPDF();

            byte[] bytes = target.toByteArray();

            HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
            header.add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .headers(header)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                    .body(bytes);

        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Document exception");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mENM9.png)
Frontend (Azure Static Web App)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY0Lz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htkfv.png)

```
    generatePdf(): void {
  this.serviceEmployee.getPdf().subscribe((response) => {
    const blob = new Blob([response.body], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  });
}

  getPdf(): Observable<any> {
    const route = ROUTES.BACKEND_ROUTE + '/employee/cv/pdf';

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      Accept: 'application/pdf',
    });

    return this.http.get(route, {
      headers: headers,
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob',
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }
```

//staticwebapp.config.json

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  },
  "mimeTypes": {
    ".pdf": "application/pdf"
  }
}
```

I tried add to staticwebapp.config.json, a line with pdf configuration but it didn't help. I also tried to git reset --hard to commits where generating pdf for sure worked on Azure but it also didn't help (it seems like file with configuartion still worked as configuartion of enabling refresh was present).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5QOi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq2Ma.png)

Answer (score 0):

Working with the little debugging information we have (a stacktrace/inner exception) would be nice to have, the first issue I see is that you frontend is adding a `Content-Type: application/pdf` header to the `GET` request it is making to your backend.

This isn't correct, as you're not actually sending a `PDF` file from the frontend to the backend. As per this post, `Content-Type` headers should only be added to `requests` using `PUT` or `POST` to describe the contents of the `body`.

In the case of your request, there is no body, and as such, there is no content of type `application/pdf`.

I would leave your `getPdf` function's `headers` content like this:

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
   Accept: 'application/pdf'
});
```